# What should we use for downloading large files from remote server. Service? IntentService? AsyncTask? Thread? or something else in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask, background-process

I am new to android, I have gone through many of the forums and discussions but still I am confused about what should I use for downloading large files from server!

In our App we are playing multiple videos in a playlist on the app frontend and meanwhile we are calling API service to get list videos in playlist, we are calling the API within an asynctask and onpostexecute method parse the API response and queue any new files to download in the downloadmanger.

The points of concern

1. Is using asynctask for fetching response from remote API enough? or is there any better option for us?
2. Calling download manager from main is a bad practice as I understand from reading, then whats the best way to go (Service, IntentService, Thread or AsyncTask)? What will be the difference of using Service, IntentService, Thread or AsyncTask in this scenario.
3. Can we execute the download when the app is kickedoff when in case of incoming call or user clicks home button, so the download should still continue and don't waste bandwidth, memory etc used for already downloaded part.
4. Can we initiate a download even if the app is in background?
5. Should we do the database operations in a different thread, is it the best practice?

public class MediaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask>
{

```
    @Override
    protected List<Media> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Media> result = new ArrayList<Media>();
        try {
            ResponseHandler responseHandlerObj = new ResponseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            result = responseHandlerObj.deviceMedia(device_id);
            media_status = responseHandlerObj.getResponse_status();
            media_msg = responseHandlerObj.getResponse_msg();
            media_version = responseHandlerObj.getMedia_version();
            medias_total = responseHandlerObj.getMedias_total();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Media> result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "status " + media_status);
        if (media_status.equals(STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
            Log.d(TAG, media_msg);
            if (device_path != null) {
                int _total_downloaded = databaseHandler.getDownloadedMediaCount(device_id);
                int _total_in_api = medias_total;
                int _downloaded_version = preferenceHelper.getDeviceMediaVersion(device_id);
                Log.d(TAG, "media_version : " + media_version + " _downloaded_version : " + _downloaded_version + " _total_downloaded : " + _total_downloaded + " _total_in_api : " + _total_in_api);
                //remove true after testing
                if (media_version != _downloaded_version || _total_downloaded != _total_in_api) {
                    databaseHandler.deleteAllDeviceMedias(device_id);
                    int id;
                    String file;
                    for (Media media : result) {
                        id = 0;

                        file = media.getFile();
                        String file_url = media.getFile_url();
                        Log.d(TAG, "media file exists: " + fileManager.checkFileExists(device_path, file));
                        if (file != null && !fileManager.checkFileExists(device_path, file) && URLUtil.isValidUrl(file_url)) {
                            media.setDownloaded(0);
                            id = databaseHandler.saveMedia(media);
                            queueDownload(file_url, file);
                        } else if (fileManager.checkFileExists(device_path, file)) {
                            long app_size = (int) fileManager.getFileSize(device_path + "/" + file);
                            long server_size = media.getFile_size();
                            long server_size_minus = server_size - 100;
                            if (app_size < server_size_minus) {
                                fileManager.deleteFile(device_path + "/" + file);
                                queueDownload(file_url, file);
                            } else {
                                id = saveDownloadedResource(media);
                            }
                        }


                    }

                }
                if (download_files.size() == 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "nothing to download");
                    preferenceHelper.setDeviceMediaVersion(device_id, media_version);
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Media: Failed to fetch data!");
        }
    }

    private int saveDownloadedResource(Media media) {
        int id = 0;

        media.setDownloaded(1);
        id = databaseHandler.saveMedia(media);
        initUpdateLayoutOnNewResource();
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: may be it's better to use `DownloadManager` which is a built in android `since level 9` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html